# Compare files in two folders using batch

Tags: batch-file

I have two folders with subfolders. I need a script that goes through each folder and checks if the files from folderA are also in folderB. If not the console should echo the file name.

My code is the following:

```
@echo off
set HMI_Kunde=C:\Test_HMI_2
set HMI_Update=C:\Test_HMI_1

for /R "%HMI_Kunde%" %%F in (*) do if not exist "%HMI_Update%\%%~nxF" echo %%~nxF

pause
```

It does show me all the files that are only in folderA, the issue is it also shows me all files from the subfolder. The subfolders have the same name, as do the files, so they shouldn't be showing up.

Comment: Then why are you using the /R option?

Comment: The entire posted batch file can be replaced by `@for %%I in ("C:\Test_HMI_2\*") do @if not exist "C:\Test_HMI_1\%%~nxI" echo %%~nxI` if just the two folders without their subfolders should be processed by the batch file. Hint: Open a command prompt window, run `robocopy /?` and read the output usage help. It could be better using in the batch file `@%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "C:\Test_HMI_2" "C:\Test_HMI_1" /L ...` and other appropriate options as explained by the help if you want to compare just the two folders or the entire folder structures.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore the subfolders, then remove the `/R` switch after `FOR`. (The "R" stands for recursive...) In your case, it is looking for files from the subfolders of `HMI_Kunde` at the root of `HMI_Update`. Since `%%~nxF` only contains the file name and not its path, it cannot find files from subfolders.

If you need to check subfolders as well, things get a bit more complicated, because the two folders are separate and simply using `%%~pnxF` will not do the job. It would be easier, if you had a different folder layout:

- HMI_Kunde=C:\Test_HMI_2
- HMI_Update=C:\Test_HMI_1\Test_HMI_2

This way, you could use `if not exist %HMI_Update%%%~pnxF ...` in your code. Is that a feasible solution in your case?

Note that it will list  files with `(*)` and folders with `(.)`. Try running the folling commands and compare the output files:

```
for %F in (*) do echo %~pnxF >> files.txt
for %F in (.) do echo %~pnxF >> folders.txt
for /d %F in (*) do echo %~pnxF >> subfolders.txt
for /r %F in (.) do echo %~pnxF >> recursive-folders.txt
for /r %F in (*) do echo %~pnxF >> recursive-files.txt
```

PS: Remember to use `%%` in the batch file and `%` from the command line for your variables.

Comment: Any success with rearranging the folder structure? Which one of the suggested `FOR` loops listed the folders you needed?

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have rearranged my folders and have broken down the function. So instead of going through the folders and subfolders in one function, I now have one for the folders and then one for the subfolders.